# Why can the wait() method be called without the notify() method when using the thread class object as a lock?

Tags: java, multithreading

```
public class WaitMain {
    public volatile static int i = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                for (i = 0; i < 1000000; i++);
            }
        };

        t1.start();
        synchronized (t1){
            t1.wait();
        }


        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

In the above code, I didn't call any notify or notifyAll methods, but the main thread still woke up and executed normally. I want to know why. Thanks.

Comment: Look at the code for `Thread.join` ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The description for this is a bit hidden in the [documentation of `Thread.join()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#join(long)) :

> As a thread terminates the `this.notifyAll` method is invoked. It is recommended that applications not use `wait`, `notify`, or `notifyAll` on Thread instances.

What happens is this:

- the main method creates a new Thread `t1` and starts it
- it then calls `t1.wait()`
- the Thread `t1` some time later terminates and implicitly calls `t1.notifyAll()` as per the documentation
- this wakes up the main thread